# Orthogonal transformation to derive function of standard normal random variables

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

$X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ are independent standard normal random variables. Find the distribution of $$T=\frac{X_1+X_2X_3}{\sqrt{1+X_3^2}}$$

Should I use orthogonal transformation to solve the above problem? What should be the transformation?

$X_2X_3=\frac{1}{2}[{(\frac{X_2+X_3}{\sqrt 2})}^2+{(\frac{X_2-X_3}{\sqrt 2})}^2]$

So we may transform $(X_1,X_2,X_3)\rightarrow (Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)$ where

$Y_1=\frac{X_2+X_3}{\sqrt 2}$ and $Y_2=\frac{X_2-X_3}{\sqrt 2}$

But what will be the form of $Y_3$?

Please anyone help me solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Find the distribution of $aX_1 + bX_2$ where $a^2+b^2=1.$  Then condition on $X_3$ with $a=1/\sqrt{1+X_3^2}.$

Comment: Details here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2335608/321264.

Comment: @whuber For a given $X_3$, $T$ will follow standard normal distribution. So we get the conditional distribution of $T$ given $X_3$. How can I prove that $T$ is independent of $X_3$?

Comment: You should be able to demonstrate that the distribution of $T\mid X_3$ is the same regardless of the value of $X_3.$

Comment: If you have solved the problem you can post an answer.